# Parsing negative numbers with argp

Tags: c, gnu, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to configure argp to interpret -1, -4, -99, etc as negative number arguments and not switches?  My C program currently allows just one switch (-v).  If I pass my program -4 as a command line argument, argp presents the error message

> invalid option -- '4'

Sample code:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <argp.h>

static const char *argpErrors[] = { "OK.", \
                      /* 01 */ "Too few arguments provided", \
                      /* 02 */ "Too many argument provided", \
                      /* 03 */ "Argument 1 must be an integer.", \
                      /* 04 */ "Argument 2 must be an integer.", \
                      /* 05 */ "Argument 3 must be an integer.", \
                      /* 06 */ "Unable to parse command line arguments." };

static struct argp_option options[] = {
    // name, key, argname, flags, doc, group
    {"verbose", 'v', 0, 0, "Produce verbose output"},
    { 0 }
};

struct arguments
{
    int argCount;
    bool verbose;
    int num[3];
};

bool isInteger(char *str)
{
    bool digitFound = false;
    int i;
    int chars = (int)strlen((const char *)str);
    for (i = 0; i < chars; ++i)
    {
        if ((i == 0) && (str[0] == '-'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            digitFound = true;
            continue;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return digitFound;
}

void reportArgpError(bool verbose, struct argp_state *state, int errorNumber)
{
    if (verbose)
    {
        argp_failure(state, 1, 0, argpErrors[errorNumber]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n", errorNumber);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

static error_t parse_opt(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state)
{
    struct arguments *arguments = state->input;
    switch (key)
    {
        case 'v':
            arguments->verbose = true;
            break;
        case ARGP_KEY_NO_ARGS:
            reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, 1);
            break;
        case ARGP_KEY_ARG:
            arguments->argCount++;
            if (arguments->argCount > 3)
            {
                reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                if (isInteger(arg))
                {                
                    arguments->num[arguments->argCount - 1] = atoi(arg);
                }
                else
                {
                    reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, 2 + arguments->argCount);
                }
            }
            break;
        case ARGP_KEY_END:
            if (arguments->argCount < 3)
            {
                reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, 1);
            }
            else if (arguments->argCount > 3)
            {
                reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, 2);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

static char args_doc[] = "num1 num2 num3";
static char doc[] = "Example for StackOverflow";
static struct argp argp = { options, parse_opt, args_doc, doc };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct arguments arguments;
    arguments.argCount = 0;
    arguments.verbose = false;
    argp_parse (&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &arguments);
    if (arguments.verbose)
    {
        puts("Success");
        printf("num1 = %d\n", arguments.num[0]);
        printf("num2 = %d\n", arguments.num[1]);
        printf("num3 = %d\n", arguments.num[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("0 %d %d %d\n", arguments.num[0], arguments.num[1], arguments.num[2]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample command:

```
./a.out -v 33 66 99
```

Response:

```
Success
num1 = 33
num2 = 66
num3 = 99
```

Sample command:

```
./a.out -v 33 -4 9
```

Response:

```
./a.out: invalid option -- '4'
Try `a.out --help' or `a.out --usage' for more information.
```

Comment: Absolutely it is possible. The responsibility to parsing args is the program's. So when you say it "allows just one switch" or "... presents the error message", you are talking about your own program and what it has decided to do. You need to post your code or be more specific.

Comment: I am thinking of preparsing the command line arguments to replace '-' characters preceeding numbers with 'n' characters, and then processing appropriately in the ARGP_KEY_ARG switch key block.  Any other ideas appreciated.

Comment: The following might work: `./a.out -v -- 33 -4 9`

Answer (score 1):

`./a.out -v -- 33 -4 9` worked.  Thank you nwellnhof.

Replacing the '-' characters with 'n' prior to calling argp_parse() and changing the 'n' back to a '-' in the ARGP_KEY_ARG switch key block also worked.  Source code below:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <argp.h>

static const char *argpErrors[] = { "OK.", \
                      /* 01 */ "Too few arguments provided", \
                      /* 02 */ "Too many argument provided", \
                      /* 03 */ "Argument 1 must be an integer.", \
                      /* 04 */ "Argument 2 must be an integer.", \
                      /* 05 */ "Argument 3 must be an integer.", \
                      /* 06 */ "Unable to parse command line arguments." };

static struct argp_option options[] = {
    // name, key, argname, flags, doc, group
    {"verbose", 'v', 0, 0, "Produce verbose output"},
    { 0 }
};

struct arguments
{
    int argCount;
    bool verbose;
    int num[3];
};

bool isInteger(char *str)
{
    bool digitFound = false;
    int i;
    int chars = (int)strlen((const char *)str);
    for (i = 0; i < chars; ++i)
    {
        if ((i == 0) && (str[0] == '-'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (isdigit(str[i]))
        {
            digitFound = true;
            continue;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return digitFound;
}

void reportArgpError(bool verbose, struct argp_state *state, int errorNumber)
{
    if (verbose)
    {
        argp_failure(state, 1, 0, argpErrors[errorNumber]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n", errorNumber);
        exit(-1);
    }
}

void replaceIntegerPrefixChar(char *str, char originalChar, char newChar)
{
    int len = (int)strlen(str);
    if (len > 1)
    {
        if ((str[0] == originalChar) && (isInteger(str + 1)))
        {
            str[0] = newChar;
        }
    }

    return;
}

static error_t parse_opt(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state)
{
    struct arguments *arguments = state->input;
    switch (key)
    {
        case 'v':
            arguments->verbose = true;
            break;
        case ARGP_KEY_NO_ARGS:
            reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, 1);
            break;
        case ARGP_KEY_ARG:
            arguments->argCount++;
            if (arguments->argCount > 3)
            {
                reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                replaceIntegerPrefixChar(arg, 'n', '-');
                if (isInteger(arg))
                {                
                    arguments->num[arguments->argCount - 1] = atoi(arg);
                }
                else
                {
                    reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, 2 + arguments->argCount);
                }
            }
            break;
        case ARGP_KEY_END:
            if (arguments->argCount < 3)
            {
                reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, 1);
            }
            else if (arguments->argCount > 3)
            {
                reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, 2);
            }
            break;
        default:
            //reportArgpError(arguments->verbose, state, false, 13);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

static char args_doc[] = "num1 num2 num3";
static char doc[] = "Example for StackOverflow";
static struct argp argp = { options, parse_opt, args_doc, doc };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct arguments arguments;
    arguments.argCount = 0;
    arguments.verbose = false;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        replaceIntegerPrefixChar(argv[i], '-', 'n');
    }

    argp_parse (&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &arguments);
    if (arguments.verbose)
    {
        puts("Success");
        printf("num1 = %d\n", arguments.num[0]);
        printf("num2 = %d\n", arguments.num[1]);
        printf("num3 = %d\n", arguments.num[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("0 %d %d %d\n", arguments.num[0], arguments.num[1], arguments.num[2]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```